# cypher cast string to integer in Agensgraph

Tags: cypher, agens-graph

I use the following query, this returns string values:

```
MATCH (n:artefact) RETURN (n.id)
```

I'm trying to cast the string to an integer, so I use the following:

```
MATCH (n:artefact) RETURN toInteger(n.id)
```

This returns the error:

```
[FAIL] BadSqlGrammarException->StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [MATCH (n:artefact) RETURN toInteger(n.id);]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function tointeger(jsonb) does not exist
```

Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I've also tried `toInt()`

I'm guessing the `function tointeger(jsonb) does not exist` is the issue, is it trying to convert the entire jsonb in an integer rather than just the `n.id`?

How do I resolve this?

I'm using Agensgraph, when I start agens browser it states `check version of AgensGraph ... v1.2 or under`

Answer (score 0):

thank you for this question.

The function `toInteger(string)` to cast only a string (not the entire jsonb) to integer has been added to Agensgraph. If you want to supress any potential errors with casting, you could also use the `toIntegerOrNull()` function.

It will be part of the new release, but the release is in progress and will be done soon. In the meantime, you can install Agensgraph from the [source code (v2.13 branch)](https://github.com/bitnine-oss/agensgraph).

With this, the cypher query:

```
MATCH (n:artefact) RETURN toInteger(n.id)
```

will cast it to integer.